# item does not implement SupportMenuItem: returning null (also with proguard)

Tags: android, proguard, android-appcompat, shareactionprovider

i'm trying to solve the "item does not implement SupportMenuItem: returning null" using the support library, but i can't figure out how to do... I've also set the proguard as indicated in the following question (i hope in correct way) [why MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider returns null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19358510/why-menuitemcompat-getactionprovider-returns-null) (see yshahak answer) but still give me the error.

Activity content (in the manifest i use the Theme.AppCompat as theme):

```
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider;

public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;
    public String default_share_text;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);
        mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(menuItem);
        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(DoShare(default_share_text));
        return true;
    }

    // Call to update the share intent
    public void changeShareIntent(Intent shareIntent) {
        if (mShareActionProvider != null) {
            mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
        }
    }

    // Share Intent 
    public Intent DoShare(String myText){
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, myText);
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        return sendIntent;
    }
}
```

activity_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/share"
    app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider" />

</menu>
```

**Proguard**

I've followed this tutorial http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html

Build.Grandle (Module App)

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                'proguard-rules.pro', 'proguard-rules-new.pro'
    }
}
```

proguard.cfg (in the root app directory)

```
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider { *; }
```

project.properties (created in the root app directory, also tried in local.properties)

```
proguard.config=proguard.cfg
```

I don't know if i've set properly proguard, but i still get the same SupportMenuItem error

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried setting proguard minify to false to check that this isn't related?

Comment: Yes, for default proguard was set to false at the begin